# As a software engineer, how should I prep for the coming recession due to coronavirus?

Tags: employment

I was pretty young in 2008 and was a child in 2000, so this will be my first recession. I am wondering what strategies one can use to maintain employability during lean times, especially factoring in that many are now working remotely and that gets rid of the hawk looking over our shoulder. That might let me pick up small amounts of contract work for example.

I am wondering how you more senior people who lived through 2008 and 2000 managed to thrive despite the poor prospects for software engineers.

I am currently employed by a large corporate entity, so my position is more secure than others, but you never know.

Comment: Improve your skills, polish your resume, contribute to open source projects.

Comment: First of all - check your contract. Depending on contract and jurisdiction you may not be allowed to work for someone other than your employer, contractor or not.

Comment: reduce spending now so that you can grow the oh crap fund you'll have to live on if laid off.

Comment: I have been a software engineer in both 2000 and 2008. Where do you live that the recession was a problem for software engineers?

Comment: I would say if you can't find job maybe try to provide one?

Comment: @nvoigt did all the hiring freezes not impact developers?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Not where I live. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Do the same things you've been doing. The same advice applies to good times and bad times. There's always going to be recessions, there's always going to be bubbles. It's not possible to predict them.

Answer (score 6):

I admittedly didn't live through those as a working employee, but I have been giving this a lot of thought lately for myself. Here is what I have done when considering this question.

1. **Evaluate your current employer.** Some companies will do just fine or even thrive in the coronavirus induced recession. Others are walking dead. I would be aggressively job hunting if I worked in customer aviation software or a low cash startup. However, I work for a government agency, the kind with defined benefit pensions. While my position is obviously not guaranteed, we currently have to fill a couple of developer positions and our work is revenue-generating, which is why my best strategy is to stay solidly put. You need to assess how likely it is that your employer will have reasons to lay you off and plan accordingly. Consider things like whether you are a contractor, whether you are a permanent or temporary hire (I was on a one year contract until two months ago, so were that still the case, I would have been aggressively applying), and how reactive your employer has been in the past to economic changes.
2. **Evaluate yourself.** A friend of mine is searching for work. One of his challenges is that he is a "Java engineer." Notice how I did not say "software engineer." He only knows backend Java and has not programmed in anything else since earning his bachelors degree. Firstly, the world has largely moved to full-stack which limits his options. Second, a lot of backend work is no longer done in Java and his market is full of newer companies that use JS for everything.
3. **Evaluate your local market.** Before I got my current job, I was primarily developing with Django. However, I am aware of just one company in my city that uses Django, so I went and beefed up on my Java knowledge and JavaScript.
4. **Build a savings account.** Maybe you are a star who lives in an excellent market, but unless you are, it could easily take you a few weeks or months to find another job. You will want something to live off until then.
5. **Pick up some non-objectionable outside work.** Working during employment hours is not something you should be doing and your contract may limit direct moonlighting in the same job. But tutoring, blogging, Udemy courses, innovation competitions, etc. are all generally non-objectionable enough to not draw too much attention. You can use this money for saving.